# How to make custom spinner in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

So, I want to make a custom spinner as you can show in the image.
Basically, a List of data will display and the mid one shows highlighted.

This design is for blood group selection. Mid data will be automatically stored in some variable.
like String selectedBg = B+;

Comment: Please check this i hope it will help you https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-cupertinopicker/#:~:text=In%20Flutter%2C%20CupertinoPicker%20is%20an%20iOS-style%20widget%20that,the%20showCupertinoModalPopup%20or%20s%20howCupertinoDialog%20function.%20Sample%20code%3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you're looking for is called the Picker, and you can look at Flutter's documentation about it.

[Cupertino Picker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html)